# Why do functions respond to .prototype but regular objects do not?

Tags: javascript, prototype, undefined, new-operator, prototypal-inheritance

Consider:

```
function Foo() {}
var x = new Foo();
```

now x and Foo have the same prototype, but only Foo responds to .prototype:

```
Object.getPrototype(x) === Foo.prototype // true
x.prototype === Foo.prototype // false

Foo.prototype // Foo {} (depending on which browser)
x.prototype // undefined
```

Why doesn't `x.prototype` work, but `Foo.prototype` does work?

Comment: `x.constructor.prototype == Foo.prototype`

Comment: Actually `x` and `Foo` do not have the same prototype: the prototype of `Foo` is `Function.prototype`. You have good answers,  some research into " javascript prototype chain" should help you along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prototype` is a property of constructors that determines what the prototype of new objects created by that constructor will be. It's only useful to have such a property on a constructor.

As long as the prototype on the constructor hasn't been changed:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf( x ) === Foo.prototype
```

and that is the same as:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf( x ) === x.constructor.prototype
```

Note that generally:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf( Foo ) != Foo.prototype
```

Comment: last line seems most helpful, specifically the fact that `Foo.protoype` is *NOT* the prototype of Foo, but the prototype of objects constructed *with* Foo.  Do I have that right?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: functions meant for `new` have `prototype`, object instances don't.

I'll probably fail in my precision in saying this, but the `prototype` is something that only applies to what you might call constructor functions, which are functions meant to be called with `new` to create instances. The prototype can be thought of as the template for the resulting instance.

For the resulting object, `prototype` is *not* a property. Rather, the properties *in* the constructor's prototype are available as properties on the instance that was created. Meaning that when you look up a property on the instance, if it's not defined on the instance, Javascript will begin checking the prototype chain to see if it's defined there.

If you want to access the prototype of an instance, use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).

The semantics of Javascript can be confusing. I highly recommend working through the free-to-read [Javascript Allongé](https://leanpub.com/javascript-allonge/read) as a way to thoroughly understand some of Javascript's finer points. Chapter 8 focuses on exactly this topic.